# Router ignores ARP response from linux

Tags: linux-networking, arp

I have just viewed my local network traffic with Wireshark to solve a connection problem of another device.
I noticed that my router constantly asks for my MAC address via ARP, but ignores the answers from my computer.
This results in an endless loop of ARP requests and responses.
When I looked at the ARP replies of my computer, I noticed the lack of padding, which is why the packages are smaller than 64 bytes.

Could that be the reason for ignoring them?

If yes, how could if fix this?

Additional information: Despite the fact that my router does not seem to know my MAC, I can use the Internet without any problems.

[Picture of Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSVVX.png)

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when there's an interface existing with same ip address but disabled. Example - a tun or tap is there but is shut down manually, by deleting that interface can fix it. Ex -

```
ip link del dev tun0
```